# Python tkinter lib not installing on Manjaro KDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, manjaro

None of my lib files are active they all have an icon next to them that looks like a txt file with a question mark.

I have tried using Tkinter and Turtle and both are having the same problems. I looked at my lib file in PyCharm to find that they are not enabled.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/crystal/PycharmProjects/practice/pong.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried using sudo install and pip install using all upper, all lower, a combo, etc. I have double checked my python3 install and it says: Python 3.10.4.
I would like to be able to activate all of my lib files and not just Tkinter and Turtle.

Comment: The error is saying that you need to install Tkinter (libtk) headers. Not just Python

Answer (score 0):

According to Arch docs, `tk` should be installed (via `pacman`, or Manjaro package manager)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Python#Widget_bindings

You can see in the package list, it installs the file mentioned in the error

https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/tk/

It's unclear what other libraries you're referring to, but not all Python extensions/modules require external C libraries